# change column spacing and font size in html 5 table based on no. of column

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I am creating an dynamic HTML table as shown in the attached screen-shot.
[image: My HTML 5 Table]
User can select multiple versions ( v1, v2 etc) and I need to show the comparison between V0 and the selected versions ( currently in image, we are showing V0 vs v1). Now the problem is:  there is too much space between the column if we select just one version to compare with.

Can we have a way to increase font-size and reduce column spacing if we just have 2 version to compare and adjust it as the no. of versions, to be compared with, increases?

As far as I know, media queries can be applied based on the screen sizes but it does not apply in my case.

Answer (score 0):

You can change the `font size` based on the `number of column` using JavaScript.

I have created sample Snippet below, have a look.

```js
var fontSize = 36;
var fontSizePerColumn = 12; // default 3 columns;

if($("table tr").children("td").length<=3){
  fontSize = 36;
}else{
  fontSize -= (($("table tr").children("td").length-3)*fontSizePerColumn);
}


if(fontSize <=12)
  fontSize = 12;


$("table tr").children("td").css("font-size", fontSize+'px');
```

```css
table tr td{
  font-family:calibri;
  font-size:36px;
  border:1px solid black;
  border-collapse:collapse;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table id="table1">
  <tr>
    <td width="50%">Column 1</td>
    <td width="25%">Column 2</td>
    <td width="25%">Column 3</td>
    <td width="25%">Column 3</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

You can check [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/nimittshah/wz05rmnh/) here.

Comment: Thanks for your input. I am planning to use pure CSS.  I discussed this with a team member and we concluded that , we can use flex box with "flex-flow: row nowrap" on tr. and Can fixed the column width to 20vw ( for example).  but than we stuck with the scenario, If we have , let's say, 10 version to compare and UI goes out of the view-port width than NO horizontal scroll bar will come as we are using  "flex-flow: row nowrap".  So now I am investigating on this aspect of whether we can have a horizontal-scroll while having "flex-flow: row nowrap" on table's tr.